# the Lead unique Id

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, opencti

I'm facing quite the issue in regards to calling up the unique id for a Lead. 
Im building out a softphone app based on the open cti system. I have no problem running my logic that determines if there is a contact and or account, my issue arises when i try to direct when a lead is existing in the database, when I run a query based on a trigger

```
*webService static String getLeads(String ani) { 
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>(); 
    for (Lead lead : [Select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Lead where Phone = :ani]){ 
        leads.add(lead);
    }
    return JSON.serialize(leads);
}*
```

Which runs the logic to determine contact information. Problem is the results I get back are old actions i performed on this lead. What I'm trying to do is query the database and get the same unique lead id that would then enable me to then redirect the sf user to that lead's contact page (https://na10.salesforce.com/**00QF000000g0flI**). Any ideas or clues? Is this even possible?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: What do you mean by "old actions"? You appear to be returning a serialized list of leads, not actions.

Comment: Not answering your question much, but a hint on style, you're reading through a list of Leads to create a list of Leads. You don't need to. This is fine: `list<Lead> leads = [Select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Lead where Phone = :ani];`

Comment: Old actions being, that through my testing i created lead, qualified lead, deleted lead. In the dev console i run the same query ie.

Comment: thanks Dominic, did try that new query. Still just gave me a result of 00QF000000fhAfpMAE, which is just an action in history showing that the lead was converted. Shows like the last point in history (conversion) with that lead or course since then i deleted it and remade.

Comment: Perhaps then im pushing the wrong string. From the browser i see that my link to a Lead detail page the url is  > https://na10.salesforce.com/00QF000000g0flI the value im expecting when i run the query is  00QF000000g0flI instead i get those actions, if i append them straight to the url its all they show (lead converted, lead deleted) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

00Q is a lead Prefix so when you say you want to return the contact I am confused (as you already said you were searching contacts)

Since you are searching for contacts already I am assuming that you DO not want to return leads that have already been converted? So here would be the code to get the lead that has not been converted and thus does not have a contact:

```
webService static String getLeads(String ani) { 
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>(); 
    for (Lead lead : [Select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Lead where Phone = :ahi AND isConverted = false]){ 
        leads.add(lead);
    }
    return JSON.serialize(leads);
}
```

If you want to look at converted leads then you will need to add the ConvertedContactID to the SQL, remove the isConverted filter or change it to true

```
webService static String getLeads(String ani) { 
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>(); 
    for (Lead lead : [Select Id, ConvertedContactID, Name, Phone, Email from Lead where Phone = :ahi AND isConverted = true]){ 
        leads.add(lead);
    }
    return JSON.serialize(leads);
}
```